# SQL query MLM database with fixed level

Tags: sql-server

I've got a database to be developed for a MLM (Multi Level Marketing) company. So, there's one customers table, each customer has a unique ID called `CustomerId`, and all customers can have customers under them can make N customers down to 1 customer.

All customers are added to the same table `tblCustomer` and for each customer there's a another table `tblCustomerUplink` where I add customer's customerId under whom that customer is.

`tblCustomerUplink` structure is look like below:

[image]

Our system have a fixed 5 level where check customer's level based on refer count and allocate level accordingly.

Suppose:

```
Level  ReferLimit  Commission
Level1    5            5
Level2    10           3 
Level3    15           2
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem. As the question is written right now, your problem is completely unclear.

Comment: What is your question? If you are wanting to model this in SQL, doing it recursively is hard. Look up the "nested set" algorithm to represent a tree using non-recursive SQL.